# Running query against all information schema in sql instance

Tags: sql, database-administration, information-schema

I know there are many variation of this question but I haven't found one that gives me exactly the results.

**Edit: I am trying to get all columns from all tables and views in all databases from the sql server instance**

I have narrowed down exactly the information I want returned from the information schema of each database but I can't quite get the syntax of the query right

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT  ''' + d.name + ''' as DatabaseName, TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA , 
TABLE_NAME , COLUMN_NAME , ORDINAL_POSITION , COLUMN_DEFAULT , DATA_TYPE , CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH 
FROM ''' + d.name + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS' 
from sys.databases d
where d.name not in('master', 'tempdb', 'msdb', 'model')


exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

I am missing something to complete my query but can't quite figure it out

Comment: An explanation of what you are trying to achieve would be helpful.

Comment: I am trying to get all columns from all tables and views in the sql server instance @GMB

Comment: You don't need dynamic SQL for list all available columns in the instance, why not directly query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`?

Comment: @GMB That only returns results for the particular database...I want for all databases in the instance